# Borel sigma field

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Is the $ \sigma $ - field generated by $[a,b]$, $a,b \in \mathbb Q $ and $ \sigma $ - field generated by $(a,b)$, $a,b \in\mathbb Q^c $ identical? Are they also the same as  Borel $\sigma $ - field.

I know that $\mathbb Q$, $\mathbb Q^c\subset$ Borel $\sigma $ - field and that Borel $\sigma $ - field contains all intervals in real line. But does that mean that the $ \sigma $ - field generated by intervals of rational numbers or irrational numbers also generate the same Borel $\sigma $ - field ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{U}=\{[a,b]\mid a,b\in\mathbb Q\}$ and $\mathcal{V}=\{(a,b)\mid a,b\in\mathbb Q^c\}$. Then we want to show that
$$
\sigma(\mathcal{U})=\sigma(\mathcal{V})
$$
and the usual way of doing this is to show the two inclusions:
$$
\mathcal{U}\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{V}),\quad\text{and}\quad\mathcal{V}\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{U}).
$$
To that end, let $[a,b]\in\mathcal{U}$. Now pick sequences of irrationals $(a_n)\subseteq \mathbb{Q}^c$ and $(b_n)\subseteq\mathbb{Q}^c$ such that $a_n\uparrow a$ and $b_n\downarrow b$. Then
$$
[a,b]=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (a_n,b_n)\in\sigma(\mathcal{V}),
$$
since $\sigma(\mathcal{V})$ is closed under countable intersections. As $[a,b]$ was an arbitrary set from $\mathcal{U}$, we conclude that $\mathcal{U}\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{V})$.

To show the other inclusion you argue similarly.

Comment: @ Stefan . That was the most succinct answer I have ever got on this site. Thanks

Comment: @Hashtag: You're very welcome.

Comment: @ Stefan. Is it possible to express an open interval like (a,b) in terms of countable unions/intersections of half closed intervals like [a,b)

Comment: @Hashtag: Yes, for example $(a,b)=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty [a+\tfrac1n,b)$

Comment: @ Stefan Will it be $ \bigcup or \bigcap $. Won't countable $ \bigcap $ give [a+1,b)?

Comment: @Hashtag: It's $\bigcap$ since if $x\in \cap_{n=1}^\infty [a+\tfrac1n,b)$, then $a+\tfrac1n\leq x<b$ for all $n$ which is equivalent to $a<x<b$.